# Maatwebsite Laravel Excel duplicate records are removed

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, excel-import

I am using Maatwebsite Excel 2.1. Now the problem is I have an excel sheet that has 5 column names, out of which two column names are the same. 
So whenever I do

```
Excel::load($path)->get()
```

I am only getting the value of the last duplicate column. For eg:

COls: First Name, LastName, Phone Number, Company Name, Company Name

Here, when I import it I am getting the value of last company name only and not the 4th one.

I cannot change the column names as they are making excel from third party govt API.

I did my research but did not get any solutions. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: whoever is down-voting, please at-least care to explain why? It will give me a chance to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PHPExcel function](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/571#issuecomment-146874492) instead

Comment: Thanx a lot. It did work. I will have to do some tweakings but got solutions. Thank you so much.